# HTML 5 Worker "threads" , spawn on Function

Tags: javascript, html

I have been reading up on HTML 5 worker threads but all the samples i have seen seem to require the javascript be in its own file.

so im basicly wondering if its posible to start a worker work directly towards a function.

The end goal here being something along the lines of:

```
function AllJavascriptIsLoaded()
{

if(gWorkersSupported)
{

        var Worker = new Worker(MyFunc)

        Worker.Start();
    }
    else 
    {
        // Horrible user experience incomming.
        MyFunc();
    }
}

function MyFunc()
{
    // Complex and time consuming tasks
}
```

Comment: If the examples require js in own file, why worry about it? Just put JS in own file. What do you mean by 'directly work towards a function?' That does not make sense to me as a programmer.

Comment: That would require a big rewrite, for example i wanted to run datatables.net in a worker. But clearly not posible without big rewrite

Comment: Ok but is not the point of a worker to 'give it a task and use it's output when it returns' So can't you structure things (and maybe you should structure them) to use this worker model? You can't use workers for UI with the DOM, but you could precache UI views if they require lots of heavy lifting using a worker, and then serve them with your main thread after they have been built. So you get performant complex UI. Is that possible for you?

Comment: Or you could inline the code in script tag and then create a blob URL which you append the textContent of that tag to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, this is not allowed for security reasons. I'd assume that a child object, or any JS script in the same file, would potentially have access to the parent DOM window, which Web Workers are not allowed to access.

So, we're stuck with posting messages to other files unless someone finds a nicer way to do it ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use something called `inline-worker`.

Basically you create a script resource via dataURI or BlobURL for the worker script. Given that the content of the script can be generated, you can use `Function.toString()` to build the content of the worker.

Example use BlobURL: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/
Example use both technique: https://github.com/jussi-kalliokoski/sink.js/blob/master/src/core/inline-worker.js

Jeffrey is right about the security restriction of WebWorker. The code running in the worker cannot access the DOM, so it should only be used for calculation heavy tasks. If you try to access the DOM inside worker's code it would raise an error.

Answer (score 1):

vkThread plugin helps you to implement exactly what you requested.

take a look at http://www.eslinstructor.net/vkthread/

there are examples for different kind of functions: regular function, function with context, with dependencies, anonymous, lambda.